# Python - scramble a sentence

Tags: python, scramble

I am trying to create a program that scrambles a word as well as a sentence. I have the code for scrambling a word, but I don't know what to do in order to scramble a sentence. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!!

```
import random

def main():
    word = input("Please enter a word or a sentence (if sentence, add a period to end the sentence: ")
    if "." in word:
        print(scramble(word))
    else:
        print(scrambleTwo(word))


def scramble(word):
    char1 = random.randint(1, len(word)-2)
    char2 = random.randint(1, len(word)-2)
    while char1 == char2:
        char2 = random.randint(1, len(word)-2)
    newWord = ""

    for i in range(len(word)):
        if i == char1:
            newWord = newWord + word[char2]
        elif i == char2:
            newWord = newWord + word[char1]

        else:

            newWord = newWord + word[i]

    return newWord

def scrambleTwo(word):


main()
```

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? What it is about scrambling a word that you don't understand that's preventing you from using it to scramble a sentence? What did you try?

Comment: This looks like homework but I can't resist: you can split your sentence into individual words and just add them to a set.  A set's order is undefined so therefore you will have your sentence scrambled.

Comment: I think your function can work with list too, so `s=sentence.split()` and then `' '.join(scramble(s))`.

Comment: you can use `random.shuffle()`, just remember to use copy of your data, as it shuffles in-place.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) your sentence on spaces like so:

```
word_list = sentence.split(" ")
```

and then scramble the resulting array in a similar fashion to how you scramble your word.

```
scramble(word_list)
```

This needs to be a different scramble functions that is tailored to scrambling an array instead of a string (the logic will be essentially the same, though).

Comment: I added the following:                                                  def scrambleTwo(word):
    s = word
    while s == word:
        s = sentence.split(" ")
        (scramble(s))
    return s

Comment: The words separate and letters are changed--how would I shuffle the order of the words in the sentence?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues with your code. One is that you can scramble single letter words but you try! You also want `raw_input` instead of just `input`. Finally the trick is to use `split` to get each word, which you then scramble. Here is a modified version.

```
import random

def main():
    word = raw_input(
        "Please enter a word or a sentence "
        "(if sentence, add a period to end the sentence: ")
    if not "." in word:
        print(scramble(word))
    else:
        print(scrambleTwo(word))


def scramble(word):
    if len(word) < 2:
        return word

    char1 = random.randint(1, len(word)-2)
    char2 = random.randint(1, len(word)-2)
    while char1 == char2:
        char2 = random.randint(1, len(word)-2)
    newWord = ""

    for i in range(len(word)):
        if i == char1:
            newWord = newWord + word[char2]
        elif i == char2:
            newWord = newWord + word[char1]

        else:

            newWord = newWord + word[i]

    return newWord

def scrambleTwo(word):
    bits = word.split(" ")
    new_sentence_array = []
    for bit in bits:
        if not bit:
            continue
        new_sentence_array.append(scramble(bit))
    return " ".join(new_sentence_array)


main()
```